# Unable to resolve "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig) error".Can anyone assist?

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3

I am trying to access objects in S3 bucket which is a JSON file and tying to open it up in Visual Studio code. But I am getting error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)"

```
import boto3
import json
import requests
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='rli-dev', region_name='us-west-2')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
content_object = s3.Object('bsdev-data-validation','awsnightlyendtoend_bsdev_2018-10-24T11:53:45Z/validate_adwactivityfact/job-details.json')

file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode()
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
print(json_content)
```

Comment: try `file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig')`

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Comment: In this case I will post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default encoding for `decode()` is `utf-8`. The traceback specify the encoding of the file is `utf-8 BOM` thus you need to pass `utf-8-sig` to `decode()`, e.g.

```
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig')
```