# Connect to another database and dumpdata from it in json format

Tags: python, json, django

My task is to populate my two existing `City` and `Province` model using two json files `cities.json' and 'provinces.json`.
Data in these files are as below.

provinces.json:

```
[
    {   "model": "salesnetwork.provinces",   
        "id": "1",
        "name": "EA"
    }
]
```

cities.json:

```
[
    {   "model": "salesnetwork.cities",
        "id": "1",
        "province_id": "1",
        "name": "Tabriz"
    }
]
```

Now I'm trying to poplulate my two models with these data. My models are as below.

```
class Provinces(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_collation="utf8mb3_unicode_ci")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "provinces"


class Cities(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey("Provinces", models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_collation="utf8mb3_unicode_ci")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "cities"
```

(My bad for naming my model `Cities` instead of `City` and `Provinces` instead of 'Province'; I've created these models via `inspectdb` command and since I didn't know if changing these model names could cause problems or not, I decided to leave the names as they were).
When I try using command  `py .\manage.py loaddata provinces.json` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 69, in Deserializer
    objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
  File "C:\Users\Vahid Moradi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 335, in loads
    raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 102, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 163, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py", line 251, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 74, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\provinces.json'::
```

and by the looks of it, this time the problem is `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)`, which I have no idea how to resolve and didn't find any instruction on how to solve this issue.
I did study the following questions, but all were for problems relating `json` library inside .py files, and since my problem occurs in command line using manage.py commands, I couldn't apply those solutions for my problem.
Possible simillar questions, but could not use the answers given:

1. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025396/asyncio-and-get-unexpected-utf-8-bom)
2. [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580965/unable-to-resolve-json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-unexpected-utf-8-bom-decode-us)
3. [Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to paste json into new file in vscode and save it.
Error`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM` because your json  files have UTF8-BOM encoding:
https://www.coderedcorp.com/blog/how-to-dump-your-django-database-and-load-it-into-/